# qemu-native error when building core-image-minimal with yocto

Tags: qemu, yocto, bitbake

I want to build the core-image-minimal with yocto and it fails. To set everything up I use the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect cmake
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git poky.git
cd poky.git
git checkout -b morty remotes/origin/morty
. oe-init-build-env
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/altera-opensource/meta-altera.git meta-altera
cd meta-altera
git checkout -b angstrom-v2015.12-yocto2.0 remotes/origin/angstrom-v2015.12-yocto2.0
```

Afterwards I add the path to `meta-altera` to `build/conf/bblayers.conf` and `MACHINE = "cyclone5"` to `build/conf/local.conf`. I would expect, that now `bitbake core-image-minimal` would run through, but it stops with the following error:

```
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/mydirectory/poky.git/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/openbios-ppc' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/mydirectory/poky.git/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/openbios-sparc32' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/mydirectory/poky.git/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/openbios-sparc64' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/mydirectory/poky.git/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/s390-ccw.img' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/mydirectory/poky.git/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/u-boot.e500' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
ERROR: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: runstrip: ''strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/mydirectory/poky.git/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.7.0-r1/sysroot-destdir/media/sln/Data/yocto/poky.git/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/palcode-clipper'' strip command failed with 1 (b"strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/mydirectory/poky.git/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.7.0-r1/sysroot-destdir/mydirectory/poky.git/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/palcode-clipper'\n")
```

I got rid of the warnings by adding `INSANE_SKIP_qemu-native = "already-stripped"` to `poky.git/meta/recipes-devtools/qemu/qemu.inc` but the error remains. I am using Ubunut 16.04 as my build machine. Any help or tipps are appreciated.

If I continue building, I get an error while building `gcc-runtime-6.2.0-r0 do_compile` and it stops. I assume that this error is based on the qemu error.

---

Here is the build config shown in bitbake:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "cyclone5"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.2.1"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp  neon        callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta              
meta-poky         
meta-yocto-bsp    = "morty:924e576b8930fd2268d85f0b151e5f68a3c2afce"
meta-altera       = "angstrom-v2015.12-yocto2.0:3cfd56bb15673795435cf7684ef9c723283a6bce"
```

Comment: The error message indicates that something is trying to strip the 'palcode-clipper' file. This is a firmware blob for Alpha emulators, so it's an Alpha ELF file. The toolchain strip (which is presumably ARM) is therefore legitimately complaining that it can't handle it. The problem is whatever it is that's indiscriminately trying to run 'strip' on every binary it can find -- you should find that and make it do something smarter instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're checking out the Yocto 2.0 branch of the meta-altera layer. Yocto 2.0 was Jethro. You're checking out the Morty branch of Poky which is Yocto 2.2. Try checking out the jethro branch of Poky with by executing the following Git command while in your poky.git folder:

```
git checkout -b jethro remotes/origin/jethro
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunate that doesn't solve the problem. Meta-altera is a really small layer and it had no influence on the result.