# Error when building Automotive Grade Linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, qemu, yocto, strip

I'm trying to build automotive grade linux, but I keep getting the same errors.
I tried building on different machines with different linux distributions, but I keep getting the error nevertheless.
I also tried building for different machines without success.

---

This is the full log of the last time I tried to build automotive grade linux for a raspberry pi 2:
Pt 1: https://pastebin.com/0pqKDdv5
Pt 2: https://pastebin.com/dmRCtTLe

---

This is my build configuration:

```
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Debian-9.3"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-agl-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "raspberrypi2"
DISTRO            = "poky-agl"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "4.0.2"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7ve vfp thumb neon vfpv4 callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta-raspberrypi  = "HEAD:28d4404f89eb59d406b4976c0e3f5ca19137ba74"
meta-netboot      = "HEAD:a5f69d3d31e7d75351f0e2abfc36d35ba39ce304"
meta-security-smack 
meta-security-framework = "HEAD:20bbb97f6d5400b126ae96ef446c3e60c7e16285"
meta-app-framework = "HEAD:a5f69d3d31e7d75351f0e2abfc36d35ba39ce304"
meta-qt5          = "HEAD:5f837b47f5c3e462f24cd5abf58ff6ef1dd04932"
meta-agl-demo     = "HEAD:65619655cb3f373a1b15da7a4d91191a2867464b"
meta-oe           
meta-multimedia   
meta-efl          
meta-networking   
meta-python       
meta-filesystems  = "HEAD:fe5c83312de11e80b85680ef237f8acb04b4b26e"
meta-ivi-common   
meta-agl          
meta-agl-distro   
meta-agl-bsp      = "HEAD:a5f69d3d31e7d75351f0e2abfc36d35ba39ce304"
meta              
meta-poky         = "HEAD:60402978fe3648bf560b3386c6e9dd661cdf2083"
```

---

This is the first error I get:

```
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/openbios-ppc' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/openbios-sparc32' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/openbios-sparc64' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/s390-ccw.img' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
WARNING: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: File '/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/u-boot.e500' from qemu-native was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging!
ERROR: qemu-native-2.7.0-r1 do_populate_sysroot: runstrip: ''strip' --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note '/.../build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.7.0-r1/sysroot-destdir/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/palcode-clipper'' strip command failed with 1 (b"strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/.../build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.7.0-r1/sysroot-destdir/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/qemu/palcode-clipper'\n")
```

This is the second error, which I think is caused by the first one.

```
ERROR: gcc-runtime-6.2.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: gcc-runtime-6.2.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /.../build/tmp/work/armv7vehf-neon-vfpv4-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc-runtime/6.2.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.30447)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /.../build/tmp/work/armv7vehf-neon-vfpv4-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc-runtime/6.2.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.30447
NOTE: recipe gcc-runtime-6.2.0-r0: task do_compile: Failed
ERROR: Task (/.../poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_6.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

---

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141223/qemu-native-error-when-building-core-image-minimal-with-yocto) of someone having the same issue, but there is no fix there, so I thought I'd ask it again, because this issue still persist.

I can see that there is a problem with the stripping of files, but I can't find where to fix this in the recipes.

I'm not sure if this error is caused by the used host system or if it's dependant on the recipes.

I hope someone knows a fix to this issue.
Thanks in advance

Laurens Wuyts

---

EDIT:

Here is the log file of the gcc error:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hd5kzgbadhdc9p/log.do_compile.30447?dl=0

Here is the specific error message on pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/H8M3sY6a

Comment: You didn't provide the log with fail: "ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/laurens/Data/Linux_Files/Bachelorproef/workspace_agl/build/tmp/work/armv7vehf-neon-vfpv4-agl-linux-gnueabi/gcc-runtime/6.2.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.30447"

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the file, I added it to the question. :)

Comment: @LaurensWuyts dropbox file is unaccesible; use pastebin

Comment: Can't you download it from the dropbox link? The file is to big to use pastebin. I have also uploaded it [here](http://www.transfernow.net/030gd1d2ige4), but it's only for a limited time.
I'll post the error from the file using pastbin.

Comment: make sure you've got `libssl-dev` package installed on your host system

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The library wasn't installed, but it didn't make a difference. I got the exact same error.
I'm now trying to build on another computer with another host system and I hope it'll be successfull.

Comment: make sure all of the following deps are installed: gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3-pip python3-pexpect libsdl1.2-dev xterm make xsltproc docbook-utils fop dblatex xmlto python-git